# Weird proxy behaviour

Tags: ssh, proxy, connection

I recently installed a computer in a network that is behind a proxy, I configured a reverse ssh tunnel to connect to it, and tunneled the ssh connection with corkscrew to connect to a server, this works without problems, but the weird thing is that it can only connect to only a server, which is completely unrelated to the proxy itself.

When I try to connect via ssh to a server, i get:

```
Proxy could not open connnection to <hostname>:  Forbidden
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Other connections, like HTML itself can establish a connection with any server without any problem, and, for example, ftp tunneled over HTTP 1.1 connect (same method as ssh) gets to login but gets dropped just before being able to list the files with the same error, and netcat gives the same behaviour as the ssh does, with the following error:

```
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

My question is why can I only connect to one specific server, is not because of the location, because I haven't access to other servers in the same datacenter, or the domain. I also had no luck with my personal ip, and have no access to the proxy itself